# Can we prove $|A| < \left|2^{2^A}\right|$ constructively?

Tags: set-theory, constructive-mathematics

Can we prove that there is no:

- Injection $2^{2^A} \to A$
- Surjection $A \to 2^{2^A}$
- Bijection between $A$ and $2^{2^A}$

Constructively?

Comment: I would be happy to try and improve the question if the person who voted to close it explained why they don't like it.

Comment: I didn't downvote or vote to close, but your question doesn't give much context. [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem) doesn't require AC.

Comment: Why $2^{2^A}$? Already with $A$ vs. $2^A$, choice isn't relevant: Cantor's diagonal argument doesn't require choice.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I wanted to ask if it is possible to prove this constructively (that is, without using LEM). The transitivity of (<) requires Schröder-Bernstein, I think, and the proof is not constructive. The proof of Cantor is constructive, but it was not clear to me whether it can be generalised to the double powerset.

Comment: The reason I am interested in this question is because I was trying to prove this in the Coq proof assistant, in which the law of excluded middle is not available unless one adds this as an axiom. Although Schröder-Bernstein is non-constructive, it seems possible that one or more of these three statements can be proved constructively, since they only assert the non-existence of certain functions. Thus, it may be possible to avoid a non-constructive intermediate step.

Comment: I suggest you [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Okay I did that.

Comment: Commenting because I can't answer - if we consider $2$ to be the two-element set (which isn't necessarily isomorphic to the set of truth values), then it's possible that $\mathbb N \cong 2^{2^\mathbb{N}}$. In particular, the axiom "every function $f:2^\mathbb{N} \to 2$ is uniformly continuous" is satisfied in the function realisability topos, and there is (always) an effective enumeration of uniformly continuous functions $f:2^\mathbb{N} \to 2$; this enumeration $\mathbb N \to 2^{2^\mathbb{N}}$ is an isomorphism in this topos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show that there is no injection from $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ to $A$ by using Cantor's theorem $|A|<2^{|A|}$. As a consequence, there is no bijection between $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$ and $A$. Since Cantor's theorem does not require any choice, we can prove the absence of injection without choice.

For the surjection part, use the following fact that is provable without choice:

> If there is a surjection from $X$ to $Y$ then $2^{|Y|}\le 2^{|X|}$.

(The proof uses inverse image: if $f:X\to Y$ is a surjection, consider $f^{-1}:\mathcal{P}(Y)\to\mathcal{P}(X)$.)

If there is a surjection from $X$ to $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$, then $2^{2^{2^{|X|}}}\le 2^{|X|}$, but we have $2^{2^{|X|}}<2^{2^{2^{|X|}}}$, so $2^{2^{|X|}}<2^{|X|}$, a contradiction.

---

As @bof pointed out, Cantor's theorem already excludes the surjection from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$, so my previous argument is verbose. Also, the OP also asked these facts hold constructively, and the answer is yes (at least over $\mathsf{IZF}$.)

Before answering, I have to point out some subtlety that came from the notation: the OP (supposedly) uses $2^A$ to denote the power set. It makes sense if we are working with classical logic. However, the power set of $A$ need not be bijective with $2^A$ *constructively*. In general, $\mathcal{P}(A)$ is bijective with $\Omega^A$ for $\Omega=\mathcal{P}(1)$. (Here $A^B$ be the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$.)

The usual proof of Cantor's theorem also works constructively, so $\mathsf{IZF}$ also proves there is no surjection from $A$ to $\mathcal{P}(A)$. Moreover, a slight modification of the proof of Cantor's theorem also shows there is no injection from $\mathcal{P}(A)$ to $A$: assume that there is such an injection $f$. Let
$$X=\{a\in A \mid \exists b\in\mathcal{P}(A) [f(b)=a\land a\notin b]\}.$$
We can see easily that $f(X)\in X$ implies $f(X)\notin X$. If $f(X)\notin X$, then there is no $b\in\mathcal{P}(X)$ such that $f(b)=f(X)$ and $f(X)\notin b$, but $b=X$ satisfies that condition, a contradiction.

*However*, the answer changes if we stick to $2^A$ instead of $\mathcal{P}(A)$: we can still show that there is no surjection between $A$ and $2^A$. The usual proof for Cantor's theorem still works. However, it is consistent with $\mathsf{IZF}$ that there are just two decidable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. (A subset $X\subseteq A$ is decidable if, for every $a\in A$, we have either $a\in X$ or $a\notin X$.) In that case, $2^{\mathbb{R}}\simeq 2$, hence $2^{2^{\mathbb{R}}}$ is embeddable into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: The proof of Cantor's theorem proves directly that there is no surjection from $A$ to $\mathcal P(A)$; consequently, there is no injection from $\mathcal P(A)$ to $A$.

Comment: Thank you! Would you also happen to know whether it is possible to prove this constructively, like Cantor's theorem can? I believe the arguments you gave make use of the Schröder-Bernstein theorem, which is non-constructive. Since the statements in the question do not seem to assert the existence of anything, I was wondering if it is possible to avoid its use and give a direct argument?

Comment: @Jules I will expand an answer for constructive cases.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!